# Ionic Material Design Iconic Font

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, material-design

Is it possible to include Googles Material desgin icon in Ionic project?

http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/icons.html

Font-Awesome work fine.

I can't find any guide for Material Design icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just use this sass rule.

```
ion-icon {
&[class*="[your-custom-icons-prefix]"] {
    mask-size: contain;
    mask-position: 50% 50%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: currentColor;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
&[class*="[your-custom-icons-prefix]-[your-icon-name]"] {
    mask-image: url(../assets/svgs/[icon_svg_file].svg);
}
}
```

You have to download the svg file and put it in a dedicaded folder i.e assets/svgs/. Then you use yout custom svg icon like so :

```
 <ion-icon name="[your-custom-icons-prefix]-[your-icon-name]"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the CDN for material-design-iconic-font in the head from your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
```

Then you can use the icon at this way:

```
<i class="zmdi zmdi-flower-alt"></i>
```

[Link to material-design-iconic-font oficial page](http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/index.html)